# Some questions about android broadcastReceiver && context.startActivity()

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-context

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("TEST", "user is present");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

I want to start my app's MainActivity at once after receiving the intent , but the MainActivity starts about 3 seconds later after I see the log "user is present" , not start at once.
And I need it to start at once for better user experiences.

I wonder wether there is a way can let the MainActivity starts faster ?

> PS: when I use a button in another activity to start the MainActivity, it starts immediately, could it be that the method "context.startActivity(i)"  in BroadcastReceiver is  more slowly ?

Answer (score 1):

There are flags that you can add to the Intent object that can help you achieve your goal. Also when the user is present, this is only after the device has been unlocked **(hint)**.

**UPDATE**

Apparently the Intent Flag is no longer in the API, bummer. However; Using the KeyguardManager you can achieve this as part of the solution to your problem.

Comment: yes, After user unlocked I want to start my app at once, not delay for 3 seconds.  but since I use the broadcastReceiver, it delays after the log " user is present"

Comment: And like I said, you can get passed this using the flags found in the Intent. Its all in the documentation, get to reading it.